# Nested loop adding first entry twice in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to compare some database columns I have in an `ArrayList` to some keys I have in a `HashMap` prior to creating an INSERT statement to insert all the `HashMap` values. The key is only part of the INSERT statement if the column is found in the database.

The problem is, that the first key is entered into the INSERT statement twice causing the execution to fail. I haven't provided the INSERT statement here or how I'm getting the values as that's not the problem, just how I'm creating the string that identifies the column names.

Here is the code:

```
ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM BRAVODay1And2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd2 = rs2.getMetaData();
ArrayList<String> che=new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd2.getColumnCount(); i++) { 
    che.add(rsmd2.getColumnName(i).trim());
}



 String prep="";
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : mapWholeBRAVO.entrySet()) {
        String key =entry.getKey().replace(":",""); 
        for (String n:che){
            if (n.equals(key)){
                prep=prep+key+",";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `key` is present several times in `che`, you will insert in `prep` the key several times

Comment: Aha. Absolutely right. I hadn't realised that I was adding to che from two tables related as a one to one both of which contained the same column name. Rectified now. ?Post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in my first comment of the question:

If `key` is present several times in `che`, you will insert in `prep` the key several times